# Calculating how much light gets through steel mesh (commonly used to make cages)

Tags: geometry, area, percentages

I have expanded steel mesh that I use to make garden cages:

[image]

I would like to know how much sunlight the mesh lets through.

I think I need to calculate the area of the mesh's negative space. And then from there I could calculate a *percentage of sunlight that is let through*.

**How can I calculate how much light would get through?**

Comment: If you really care about the light (not just using it as a model for the area calculation) then the angle of the sun will matter since the cell dividers have a nontrivial thickness and will cast shadows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Crop the ruler and binarize:

[image]

Then count the white pixels and divide by the sum of white and black to find:

$0.592548$

In *Mathematica*:

```
pixels = Flatten[
   ImageData[
     Binarize[
      ImageTake[mesh, {140, 664}, {1, 892}]]]];
N@Count[pixels, 1]/(Count[pixels, 0] + Count[pixels, 1])
```

$0.592548$

People wanted a different threshold:

[image]

Comment: Do I get the green $\checkmark$?

Comment: Seems a little high, do you think there should be some preprocessing for the shadows?

Comment: Maybe you could binarize with a threshhold and adjust to find the right value.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber:  See my modified answer.

Answer (score -1):

**I can use Geographic Information Systems (GIS) software to plot and calculate the area of the negative space:**

1. Crop the image down to a more manageable size (in Microsoft Paint).
2. In GIS software, draw a rectangle around the image to get it's area.
3. Draw polygons in the negative space.

> Area of image  = 147542 units
>
> Area of negative space = 92907 units

4. Calculate the percentage of negative space:

> 92907 / 147542 = **62.97%**

[image]

Therefore, approximately 63% of light would get through this mesh.

Comment: I suppose the calculation will be skewed, because the GIS software is **projected** (UTM projection). This will affect the area calculations--but only ever so slightly.